# how to check if s3 bucket exist and if not, create it if yes take it in typescript cdk?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I need to check if a bucket exist in the account and create one if the bucket does not exist or use the already existing bucket

I tried to doit like this:

```
import {Bucket} from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3';

const bucketName = 'testing-bucket-12345';
const checkBucket = Bucket.fromBucketName(this, bucketName, bucketName);
if (!checkBucket) {
    console.log("testinggggg new bucket")
    // Create the S3 bucket if it does not exist
    new Bucket(this, bucketName, {
        bucketName: bucketName
    });
}
```

but looks like the CDK does not read these lines

Comment: @fedonev there are plenty of readonly use cases for s3 buckets in CDK

Answer (score 0):

The Bucket.fromBucketName(...) is used to identify what I will call a "foreign" bucket, meaning one not originally created in this stack. CDK stages things assuming this foreign bucket exists, and later throws an error during stack building if it does not. I think what you want to do is check if the foreign bucket exists, otherwise create a bucket that is not "foreign" in this stack and, importantly, keep it in stack updates. This gets messy.

To keep a stack-created bucket in stack updates, the "new Bucket()" command needs to be executed by CDK unconditionally, which can be unintuitive at first. On an update, CDK interprets the "new Bucket()" operation to mean that this bucket should continue to be in the stack. If the "new Bucket()" command is only executed when the bucket does not exist and skipped otherwise, the bucket will be created in the initial build of the CDK stack as expected, but it will be deleted in any update.

Unfortunately, what this means is you are really looking for a way to code "Create a bucket managed in this stack if a foreign bucket by this name does not exist". I don't know how to do this cleanly in CDK (but there is a "messy" suggestion below), and after thinking about it, I don't recommend this approach. Instead, there should be a design decision about whether to use a "foreign" bucket or one created by the given CDK stack. If the design decision is to use a foreign bucket, then it needs to be created elsewhere, e.g. by another stack created before this one in /bin, by aws cli, or in the AWS browser.

**messy suggestion** with help from AWS support:

1. In the constructor after new Bucket(...), add a tag to the new Bucket to distinguish it from a foreign bucket:

```
if (!foreignBucketExists) {
    // Use a bucket managed by this CDK stack if a foreign stack by this name does not exist
    const myBucket = new Bucket(this, bucketName, {
        bucketName: bucketName
    });
    Tags.of(myBucket).add("CreatedBy", "<a name for this stack>")
} else {
const myBucket = Bucket.fromBucketName(this, bucketName, bucketName);
}
```

2. In /bin, check if a bucket by this name exists, and if it does, check its tags to see if it is a "foreign" bucket with respect to this stack. Assign the result to foreignBucketExists, which then needs to be piped to the stack constructor in step 1:

```
// check if a bucket by this name exists
let request = new AWS.S3().listObjects({
    Bucket: MyBucketName
});

let promise = request.promise();
// handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
await promise.then(result => {
    foreignBucketExists = true
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("No Such Bucket exists.")
    foreignBucketExists = false
})

// If the bucket exists, check if the bucket has the tag from the CDK stack, in which case it is not a foreign bucket

if (foreignBucketExists) {
    try {
        let tagRequest = new AWS.S3().getBucketTagging({
            Bucket: MyBucketName
        });

        let tagPromise = tagRequest.promise();
        await tagPromise.then(result => {
            for (let KeyVal of result.TagSet) {
                if (KeyVal.Key == "CreatedBy" && KeyVal.Value == "<a name for this stack>") {
                    //bucket exists but was created by CDK, so it is not a foreign bucket
                    foreignBucketExists = false;
                }
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            // If the bucket has no tags, it is definitely a foreign bucket. 
            // Not really needed because we are in "if (foreignBucketExists)", 
           // but this makes the logic a little bit more clear.
            foreignBucketExists = true  
        })
    } catch {}
} 

console.log("Does bucket Exist?:", foreignBucketExists)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are asking for is exactly what AWS CDK (or AWS CloudFormation, to be exact) already does for you: You simply define something like

```
const myBucket = new Bucket(this, bucketName, {
        bucketName
    });
```

and if the bucket already exists, CloudFormation will use that. If it doesn't, CloudFormation will create it. So in any case, after that line of code, you will be able to use the bucket object.

What is a bit strange at the beginning is that CDK doesn't actually create AWS resources. It just "synthesizes" your code to some JSON template, and CloudFormation then takes it to find out the differences between what you defined and what is already there.

Comment: That's not how CloudFormation works - this code will always attempt to create the bucket on first deployment and will fail if it already exists.